# Why are files not accessible from Windows 7 while accessible from XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, filesystems, file-management

I have a removable hard drive formatted to NTFS and hooked into a media streamer. When I unplug the drive from the streamer and plug it into my windows 7 system (the same one I used one format that drive!), I can see and access all the folders, but I am unable to do anything else. When trying to delete or copy any file to and from the drive, I get a file not found error. That's clearly not correct since, as I said, I can see that file in explorer or the command prompt.

If I plug the drive to an XP SP2 system I can do anything I want including copy and delete.

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Do a file system check. Windows 7 might also have permission issues. Since they're different OSes, the security might be counting against you.

Comment: I tried looking at the security settings in windows 7,  got an error saying that security data is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

1. Run a check dsk
2. take ownership of the root folders (right click/properties/security tab/advanced)
3. change permissions in the folders making sure your user have full access permision. Be sure to check "Replace all child permissions..."

BTW, once I had a USB drive formated with OSX.  In windows it showed as a read only CD Driver. I HAD TO plug it again in OSX to be able to format the HD.

Answer (score 0):

On win7, run these commands:

```
Start > Run [as admin] these cmd

:: /f file, /a admin,  /r recurse, /d y = nopromt
takeown /F . /A /R /D Y > nul:

:: /t /q /c .. traverse quiet continue
icacls . /t /q /c /reset
icacls . /t /q /c /grant    :r Everyone:F
icacls . /t /q /c /setowner Administrators
```